# SELECT on varbinary column using string representation of binary search term

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I am inserting IPs into varbinary column. Sequel PRO represents this as values as gibberish ( Ü×L%>¨€NóP). When I am manually searching, I'd like to use that gibberish to find the matching rows:

```
SELECT * FROM `IP_MAP` WHERE `ip` = BINARY(" Ü×L%>¨€NóP")
```

Such query does not return any rows, although I copy pasted the varbinary from Sequel PRO interface. What is the correct way to search varbinary columns when given string representation of the varbinay?

Sample table:

```
CREATE TABLE `IP_MAP` (
  `id` bigint(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `ip` varbinary(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `ip` (`ip`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Comment: If you have MariaDB-10.5+ there is an [inet6](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/inet6/) type that stores IPv4 and IPv6.

Comment: Try searching exactly the way value was inserted. E.g. `insert IP_MAP(id, ip) select 1, '8.8.8.8'; select * from IP_MAP where ip='8.8.8.8';`

Answer (score 0):

Use [INET6_NTOA()](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/inet6_ntoa/) and [INET6_ATON()](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/inet6_aton/) functions.

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM `IP_MAP` 
WHERE `ip` = INET6_ATON('48f3::d432:1431:ba23:846f')
```

Comment: When working with UI,  "true" IP is not presented in the human readable form, only in binary. Will use views if better approach is not found.